# Не могу прогнать миграцию postgres БД

Tags: postgresql

При попытке прогнать мои миграции, я получаю сбой при проверке подлинности, хотя пароль и логин у меня прописаны верно. Я попробовал сделать это через пользователя postgres, но получил ошибку с адресом вообще левой директории. Попробовал запустить через рут, возникает аналогичная ошибка.
Юзаю эту либу https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/tree/master/cmd/migrate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы переключились на пользователя `root` и находитесь в каталоге `/root`, а не в рабочем каталоге вашего проекта.

Про оригинальную ошибку [давно известны решения](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7695962/1892060).

Comment: Сожалею, но не один из способов не помог. Я просто не могу найти pg_hba.conf в/etc/postgresql/9.x/main

Comment: Значит, у вас либо версия не `9.x`, а `10` или `11`, либо _PostgreSQL_ установлен в нестандартное место, либо вообще не установлен. Тут уже вам самим нужно разобраться в своих машинах.

Comment: Да, я использую 10 версию. А что с ней не так?

Comment: Ну и ищите в `/etc/postgresql/10/main`.